Does anyone know why beef has a meaning of "complaint" or "argument"?
I heard my friend saying "what's the beef" when she was curious about what is going on in a drama. I was confused at that time, but later found out that she was asking about the situation. This is quite interesting to me. It would be appreciated if anyone knows and shares the evolution of its meaning.

Did you attempt no research before asking?

Etymon has 'beef (v.)
"to complain," slang, 1888, American English, from noun meaning "complaint" (1880s). The noun meaning "argument" is recorded from 1930s. The origin and signification of these are unclear; perhaps they trace to the common late 19c. complaint of soldiers about the quantity or quality of beef rations.'

It's not clear. To beef in the late 19th century also meant to slaughter cattle and hence metaphorically to kill or hit somebody (OED), and Green's has beef as slang with several other meanings including penis, to inform on someone, and (to make) an error. You could guess lots of connections from that (e.g. from hitting someone to getting in an argument).

Or there's biff meaning hit, violence, trouble, from late 19th century, presumably onomatopoeically.

OED does not have the noun used this way, but it does have the verb

beef verb, intransitive
4. To complain, grumble, protest.
slang (originally U.S.).

An example provides a possible origin??

1888
He'll beef an' kick like a steer an' let on he won't never wear 'em.
New York World 13 May (Farmer)

